# Permutations in products of disjointed cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

How do I calculate the following permutation in the symmetric group $S_6$ giving
the answers as products of disjoint cycles: $$(2,3,5,6)(1,6,2,4)$$

I have tried following [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698281/permutations-as-produce-of-disjoint-cycles) but I don't understand the process of reading right -> left as it seems to change direction and I don't truely understand why.

Comment: Can you point out on which line it seems to "change direction"? Then it would be easier to help you understand the procedure.

Comment: "We first take 1 (reading from right to left), and we see that 1 goes to 3"
 - Starting with 1, you can loop back round to the end to get 3. 
"we see that 3 goes to 5"
 - Surely 3 goes to 2, if reading right -> left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product (composition) of these two permutations looks like this.

$$\begin{array}{ccccccr} 1&2&3&4&5&6& \\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow& (1,6,2,4)\\
6&4&3&1&5&2&\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&\downarrow&(2,3,5,6)\\
2&4&5&1&6&3 \end{array}$$

So in the product you have $(1,2,4)(3,5,6)$.

With a bit of practice, you don't need to write out the complete functions.

Comment: Thanks very much. I understand this the best.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

Begin with one: "one goes to six (on the right, of course), which then goes to 2 (on the left), so one goes to two" : $\;1\to 2\;$ .

Now with two: "two goes to four which then doesn't move" , so $\;2\to 4\;$ .

Continue as above until a cycle is closed and then begin with the smallest number left, if any, and etc.:

$$(2\;3\;5\;6)(1\;6\;2\;4)=(1\;2\;4)(3\;5\;6)$$

Answer (score 1):

Cycles are functions. The product of two cycles is just a composition of two functions, thus we read right to left. First look at $(4 1 3)$, then $(1 2 3 5)$. But *inside* the cycle you read left to right, that is $4 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4$.